First Name & Last Name drop down list
When searching for Dropdown list for two columns I get results for dependent drop down lists which is not what I am trying to achieve.
I have a list of first names in column A, and a corresponding list of last names in Column B.

STAFF LIST  |   No of Staff:    |   6
NAME        |   
FIRST       |   LAST        
John        |   Doe     
Rob         |   Zombie      
Kat         |   Canine      
Kitty       |   K9      
Anne        |   van Dam     
Mr          |   T

I can combine them using the following array formula:
{=STAFF_List}

The named formulas are as follows:
STAFF_Count=COUNTA('STAFF LIST'!$A:$A)-3
'-3 due to three header rows

STAFF_List='STAFF LIST'!$A$4:INDEX('STAFF LIST'!$A:$A,STAFF_Count+3)&" "&'STAFF LIST'!$B$4:INDEX('STAFF LIST'!$B:$B,STAFF_Count+3)
'+3 due to three header rows

When I use =STAFF_List in an array formula formula it works perfectly.

When I use =STAFF_List in a data validation list option I do not get any options.  Actually I get an error message box first that says the formula evaluates to an error.
What am I doing wrong?
What can I do to make a data validation list that has the full name from the names stored in two columns?
Note I am using excel 2013 and I am trying to avoid the use of a helper column.

Use the formula to generate a list of names and use that range to create a Data Validation List? Put the helper column on a hidden sheet

@cybernetic.nomad is there a way to do it without the helper column?

looks like it does not play well with a range being defined by INDEX():INDEX() within data validation.

@ForwardEd arrays don't work within Data-Validation. You need to reference a List/Range using helper columns as mentioned above !

@nkalvi I am using excel 2013.  You have to apply the array formal to a range to get more than one entry to display.

@nkalvi 15.0.5571.1000

Thanks to your question, I was curious to see whether there's any way to avoid using helper columns. While exploring, I was able to find this:
Microsoft Excel: Advanced spreadsheet modeling using Dynamic Arrays - BRK4001 - YouTube
now I have a better understanding of array formulas both past and present.

For data validation, using defined names with INDEX is fine as long as they return a reference to a range.
My answer here is just to show my trial with Excel 2013, and not trying to use something already said by others (though I have used table lookups before.)

If using tables (as in Frank Ball's answer) with calculated columns is feasible, you could just define a name, without using INDIRECT (cannot use tables directly, yet):


With named ranges (as cybernetic.nomad suggested)

Enter your array formula with a large enough range selected ($L$2:$L$35); I named it lookup_range
Define a name for the lookup (staff_list), trimming the range (used COUNTIF to count the cells with at least one character)
=INDEX(Lookup_range,1,1):INDEX(Lookup_range,COUNTIF(Lookup_range,"?*"),1)





Format your data as Structured Table (Select your data, including headings and press Ctrl+t, make sure "My Table has Headers" is checked, Click "OK").  Your default Table Name will be Table1 (as long as there aren't any other Tables in your worksheet).  For your List in the Data Validation dialog, use the following:
=Indirect("Table1[Full name]")

